# I am trying to setup some auditd rules but getting error -F missing operation for auid

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, auditd, hardening

i am trying to setup the below rule in /etc/audit/audit.rules

```
-a always,exit -S unlink -S unlinkat -S rename -S renameat -F auid>= 1000 -F auid!=4294967295 -k delete
```

which didn't work so i tried executing it directly from command line as so :

```
auditctl -a always,exit -S unlink -S unlinkat -S rename -S renameat -F auid>= 1000 -F auid!=4294967295 -k delete
```

But i am getting the following error :
-F missing operation for auid

Can someone guide me on how to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Executing the mentioned lines leads to greater than sign `>` being interpreted as redirect operator by your shell, which is presumably `bash`. For that reason the operation for `auid` is missing, because everthing after `>` is not part of the command anymore. You probably see a file named `=` in your current directory.

To properly execute you have to escape `>` for example like this:

```
auditctl -a always,exit -S unlink -S unlinkat -S rename -S renameat -F auid\>= 1000 -F auid!=4294967295 -k delete
```

or like this:

```
auditctl -a always,exit -S unlink -S unlinkat -S rename -S renameat -F "auid>=1000" -F auid!=4294967295 -k delete
```